# HMR Webpack Configuration, giving a 404

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am trying to achieve some sort of auto reloading in my project using webpack-dev-server and react-hot.

I am using babel to transform my js from a src directory to a public directory.

With my current config I can see that the .json and .js update files are making it to the public directory.

But in my error console I can see this:

app.js:4473 GET http://localhost:3000/sockjs-node/info?t=1473946358314 404 (Not Found)AbstractXHRObject._start @ app.js:4473(anonymous function) @ app.js:4362
app.js:795 [WDS] Disconnected!

I have a webpack.config.js (baseConfig) which looks like this:

```
require('dotenv').config();
var path = require('path');
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var precss = require('precss');
var cssnano = require('cssnano');

var ROOT_PATH = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src');
var BUILD_PATH = path.resolve(ROOT_PATH, '../public');

module.exports = {
    entry: '',
    output: {
        path: BUILD_PATH,
        filename: 'app.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/, // test for js and jsx files only
                loader: ['babel'],
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                query: {
                    "presets": ["es2015", "react"],
                    "ignore": ["/node_modules/"],
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loaders: [
                    'isomorphic-style-loader',
                    'css-loader',
                    'postcss-loader'
                ],
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    },
    postcss: function() {
        return [autoprefixer({browsers: ['last 2 versions']}), precss, cssnano];
    },
    plugins: []
}
```

Also a webpack-client-config.js, which looks like this:

```
require('dotenv').config();
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var ROOT_PATH = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src');
var BUILD_PATH = path.resolve(ROOT_PATH, '../public');

var baseConfig = require('./webpack.config.js');

baseConfig.entry = [
    'webpack/hot/dev-server',
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000',
    (ROOT_PATH + '/client-render.js'),
];

baseConfig.plugins = [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
]

baseConfig.devServer = {
    hot: true,
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:3000'
}

module.exports = baseConfig;
```

I have obviously mis-understood something about webpack, anyone care to enlighten me as to why this is not working? I can visit localhost:3000/app.js and can see the script right there in the browser. I set public as static with express.

Comment: Are you using webpack 2.0.beta? Did you resolved this issue? I am facing the same issue now.

Comment: No I have not resolved or looked at this again as yet, but I may have another dig into it later in the week.